# electric heater keeps needing to be reset by turning fan on and off atleast every 1-2 days

Tags: hvac

My electric furnace is about 23 years old, it quits working but does not trip a breaker. It feels warm to hot at furnace and just kind of clicks occasionaly when I turn thermostat up to 90 to try and get it to kick on.  If I turn the switch on at the furnace and back to auto it will work again for a day or two.
It almost acts as though it is shutting down for safety reasons.

I am considering getting a heat pump. What should I do?

Comment: The motor may be overheating and tripping a safety , it is possible the bearings have dried out and need some fresh lubricant.

Comment: Do you mean the fan does not blow?  It sounds like it is making heat.  There's very little to go wrong in an electric heater (proper, not the fan).

Answer (score 1):

I have to say it's time for you to get an HVAC Pro, please. There's a fault in the system & your "reset" is just working until the fault trips again. Unless, you're getting a Heat Pump next week pay $100 or $300 to a someone who knows what they're doing. Then, you can take years to decide on replacing the system. You resets could very well be pushing something that needed adjustment to the point of needing replacement. Spend a few bucks every 5-years on any type of system for continuous comfort & enjoyment.